# How can I increase the number of spelling suggestions in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, spell-check

After a recent upgrade, I'm usually only getting two (wrong) spelling suggestions in various programs. I used to get like 10 suggestions. How can I increase this?

I spell phonetically and need the guesses to be more liberal.

This is Linux Mint 19.1. It's Lyx in particular, but other programs are limited in suggestions too.

Comment: Make more mistakes. :D

Comment: What's giving you the spelling suggestions, the programs themselves, like Lyx? Or some 3rd party (onscreen?) keyboard?

Comment: In Lyx, there is a "spellcheck engine" option. The only choice is "enchant".